# Use CSS/Javascript received through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm experimenting with the jQuery UI tab control, and have three tabs that each load a different page through AJAX. The pages that are loaded are complete html-pages, with their own Javascript and CSS.

Scripts that are inline in the html body are ok, so are CSS in the style-attribute on tags, but Javascript and CSS in the head of the loaded pages are not used at all.

How can I make use of the Javascript and CSS in the head of the loaded pages? Or do I have to include all CSS and Javascript in the page containing the tab control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX load is going to filter out anything that's not in the body element.  You can put the CSS/Javascript tags in the body and they will be added to your page, but I would avoid that if at all possible.  If you're not careful, you'll end up including things multiple times.

I suggest putting the common stuff like jQuery itself, plugins, etc. on the page containing the tabs and only put tab-specific scripts on the bits that are loaded via AJAX.  You'll need to be careful to manage ids -- they have to be globally unique, not unique within the tab.  Sticking with classes may be a better way to handle this or preface your ids with the tab name.  For CSS I would try to make it so the CSS applies to the entire page, including tabs, and load it with the page.

YMMV.

Comment: Seems to much of a hassle, I think I just continue working without the tab-control, and just use normal links between pages.

Comment: @Joachim - In practice I don't find it to be.  It's probably easier to start this way that to retrofit something into tabs, but honestly I haven't had much trouble.  Of course, ASP.NET MVC might make this easier than some other frameworks because of the separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You could add this line in your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="yourid" type="text/css" />
```

and this after your ajax call:

```
document.getElementById('yourid').href='css/'+yourvariable+'.css';}
```

And you can do the same for scripts (change rel and type).